# razorpay payment integration in mern

Tags: mern

#### *Hello, I am integrating Razorpay payment gateway method in my mern stack project. Its work and show card, netbanking, wallet, pay later options only. it not show the upi option here any one can help me to resolve this issue. I an sharing the image regarding.*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4PzN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUcpC.png)

my server.js code

```
router.post("/checkout", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { totalPrice } = req.body;
    const { totalprice } = totalPrice;
    const amount = totalprice; // Convert totalprice to paisa
    console.log('Request Body:', req.body);
    console.log('Total Amount:', totalprice);
    console.log('Amount in paisa:', amount); // Log the amount in paisa

      // Create order with total price
      const options = {
          amount, // Convert totalPrice to the smallest currency unit (e.g., paisa)
          currency: "INR",
          receipt: "receipt#1",
          payment_capture: 1,
         

          
      };
      const order = await instance.orders.create(options);
      console.log(order);
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, order });
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during checkout:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Error during checkout' });
  }
});

//payment verification
router.post("/paymentverification", async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const { razorpay_order_id, razorpay_payment_id, razorpay_signature } = req.body;
      const body = razorpay_order_id + "|" + razorpay_payment_id;
      const expectedSignature = crypto.createHash('sha256', process.env.RAZORPAY_API_SECRET)
          .update(body.toString())
          .digest('hex');
      const isAuthentic = expectedSignature === razorpay_signature;
      if (isAuthentic) {
          await razorpayment.create({ razorpay_order_id, razorpay_payment_id, razorpay_signature });
          res.redirect(`http://localhost:3000/success?reference=${razorpay_payment_id}`);
      } else {
          res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid signature' });
      }
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during payment verification:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Error during payment verification' });
  }
});

router.get("/api/getkey", (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).json({ key: process.env.RAZORPAY_API_KEY });
});
```

my checkout.js file code reactjs

```
const checkouthandler = async (totalPrice) => {
    try {
      console.log('Total Price:', totalPrice); // Log totalPrice before making the request

        // Fetch Razorpay key
        const { data: { key } } = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/getkey");

        // Create order with total price
        const { data: { order } } = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/checkout", { totalPrice });

        // Prepare payment options
        const options = {
            key,
            totalprice: order.totalprice,
            currency: "INR",
            payment_method: 'upi',
            name: "Sinmplyjs",
            description: "Razorpay tutorials",
            image: "",
            order_id: order.id,
            
            callback_url: 'http://localhost:5000/paymentverification',
            prefill: {
                name: "raj gupta",
                email: "raj@gmail.com",
                contact: "1234567890"
            },
            notes: {
                "address": "razorpay official"
            },
            theme: {
                "color": "#3399cc"
            }
        };

        // Initialize Razorpay and open payment dialog
        const razorpay = new window.Razorpay(options);
        razorpay.open();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during checkout:', error);
        // Handle error
    }
}
```